# Updating a form field with a link

Tags: html

I have access to form field in the administrative view.

Example

```
<label>Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="title" size="50"/><br/>
```

I do not have access to modify the html syntax, the only thing i can do is updating the form field with a value.

In the form field i want to update it with a number. I also want to have a link assigned to that number.

So when i click that number it directs us to the link.

Is there a way i can do that?

Comment: First, your label element needs a for attribute to do anything. Second, you'll need JavaScript or jQuery to do what I think it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This method is tedious, but you could use the jQuery nth-selector to select the specific form element that you are dealing with.

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

This method is risky, however, since you might add other form elements before it, altering the index of your target input element.

Afterwords, you could use the `.val()` jQuery method to change your input value.

Nonetheless, again, this method is not safe because the index of the form element could change. I would beg the powers of be to be able to add an ID or some identifying attribute to that form element.